# vector push_back after curly braces initializer does not work in C++

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I have a vector with `{}` initializer. And then I use `push_back` to add an element into the vector. 
When I print the vector elements, the pushed element does not print. Why is that?

```
int main() {
    vector<int> vec = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    vec.push_back(1);

    cout << "size = " << vec.size() << endl;

    cout << "vals: ";
    for (auto &v : vec) {
        cout << v << "\t" ;
    }
}
```

Output:

Value 1 should be printed, but it does not.

```
size = 11                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
vals: 0 1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
```

Comment: Sounds like an output problem. Add a `cout << endl` after your for loop (to flush the buffer).

Comment: `cout` is unbufferred.

Comment: Works fine in Visual Studio 2019. What's your platform? What do you get *without* the `push_back`?

Comment: Works fine with ```cout << v << "\t" << endl;```,  however ```cout << v << "\t" << flush;``` does not work. I am using this online compiler https://www.onlinegdb.com/ and choose C++17.

Comment: @YunLi look at the very right of the console. Somehow the tabs are broken there :D

Comment: Oh stupid me! Thanks!

Comment: @JasperKent `cout` is buffered but it is automatically flushed before a program ends.

Comment: Regardless of flushing, C++ streams require a newline at the end of the output. Some systems won't show output without it; others will. `std::endl` writes a newline and does some other, usually unnecessary, stuff.